# User input to set cal month and year in linux shell script

Tags: linux

I am writing a shell script for a linux class and have been unable to determine how to apply the user input to the calendar. I am reading the month and year from the user and need to display the calendar with the indicated month and year.

I'm not sure how to make cal show the month and year entered? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this example help?

```
#!/bin/bash
month=$1
year=`date +%Y`

cal $month $year
```

get the command line parameter to set the month

set the year with the date command

call cal